# How to allow access to users not in database in Symfony 2

Tags: symfony

Running Symfony 2.4.4. I am authenticating users against LDAP (via IIS Authentication) and then loading that user from the database via the Entity User Provider.

This works fine.

However, I would like to give visitors to my app that do not have accounts in my database access to certain parts of the app (specifically, public reports). When I try to create a user with no roles, I get a "`UsernameNotFound Exception`" from `/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bridge/Doctrine/Security/User/EntityUserProvider.php`

Is there a way to give a user an Anonymous Token or a visitor role when they are not in the database?

Comment: I've ended up creating a Guest user in the database and managing permissions on that user. Anyone without an account in the system is logged into the system as the Guest User.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is there a reason you want to handle these users separately, without adding them to the database? I have a very similar setup to yours in an application I wrote recently, and I simply add the user with a basic role if they do not already have an account. Assuming you're implementing UserProviderInterface:

```
public function loadUserByUsername($username) {
    $q = $this
        ->createQueryBuilder('u')
        ->where('u.username = :username')
        ->setParameter('username', $username)
        ->getQuery();

    try {
        // The Query::getSingleResult() method throws an exception
        // if there is no record matching the criteria.
        $user = $q->getSingleResult();
    } catch (NoResultException $e) {
        // If the user successfully authenticated but doesn't exist
        // in our database, create a user with BASIC role
        $em = $this->getEntityManager();
        $roles = $em->getRepository('AcmeEntityBundle:Role')->findBy(array(
            'role' => 'ROLE_BASIC'
        ));
        $user = $this->createUser($username, $roles, array());
    }

    return $user;
}
```

Comment: I'm not fond of adding dozens to hundreds of users to my database that are just duplicating information from Active Directory if I don't have to. But I do like the idea of having something in the DB. See my comment to the original question for what I did.